# Updating Drupal from 8.3.7 to 8.5.1 using composer

Tags: drupal-8

I am new to Drupal and am trying to understand the update process. I am running Drupal 8.3.7 on an Amazon server. I set my site into maintenance mode. Then I try to update like this:

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

However it has no effect. So I read the you can check for blocking dependencies with the following command:

```
composer prohibits drupal/core:8.5.1
```

Below are the results, but I don't know how to proceed from here. Do I need to add dependencies into the "require" section of my composer.json?

```
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          asm89/stack-cors (^1.1)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  does not require  asm89/stack-cors (but 1.0.0 is installed)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          symfony/class-loader (~3.4.0)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  requires          symfony/class-loader (~2.8)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          symfony/console (~3.4.0)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  requires          symfony/console (~2.8)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          symfony/dependency-injection (~3.4.0)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  requires          symfony/dependency-injection (~2.8)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          symfony/event-dispatcher (~3.4.0)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  requires          symfony/event-dispatcher (~2.8)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          symfony/http-foundation (~3.4.0)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  requires          symfony/http-foundation (~2.8)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          symfony/http-kernel (~3.4.0)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  requires          symfony/http-kernel (~2.8)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          symfony/process (~3.4.0)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  requires          symfony/process (~2.8)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          symfony/routing (~3.4.0)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  requires          symfony/routing (~2.8)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          symfony/serializer (~3.4.0)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  requires          symfony/serializer (~2.8)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          symfony/translation (~3.4.0)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  requires          symfony/translation (~2.8)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          symfony/validator (~3.4.0)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  requires          symfony/validator (~2.8)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          symfony/yaml (~3.4.5)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  requires          symfony/yaml (~2.8)
drupal/core    8.5.1  requires          twig/twig (^1.35.0)
drupal/drupal  8.3.7  does not require  twig/twig (but v1.25.0 is installed)
```

**UPDATE:**

I removed "drupal/core: ~8.3" from "replace" and added "drupal/core: ~8.5" to "require" (not sure if this is correct approach, but at this point I'm trying anything)

and then tried to run update again and get this error:

```
Package is not installed: drupal/drupal-8.3.7.0
```

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, I added "drupal/core: ~8.3" to require, and it updated to 8.3.9, then I changed it to "drupal/core: ~8.4" and it removed core, then I changed it to "drupal/core: ~8.5" and it seems to have updated, but I have a few errors on my site. For example, the "configuration" page returns "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." So obviously I am not doing this right. Any advice would be great. The dependencies don't seem straightforward and I hope this I don't have to go through this process every month. :(

Comment: after updating using `composer`, did you run the `updated`b & `entup` command via drush `drush updatedb` & `drush entup` ? Checkout the Drupal doc: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update